# which MAKE or which MAKES

Tags: relative-pronouns

Regarding the usage of the relative pronoun "which", after it, do you use singular verb or plural?

> ”Historic buildings enliven the memories of how people lived in the past, which **make** each country fascinating as every nation has different stories to tell.

Or

> Historic buildings enliven the memories of how people lived in the past, which **makes** each country fascinating as every nation has different stories to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is really whether the subject of the verb **to make** is singular or plural.

To answer the question, reduce the subject to its essence:

> Historic buildings enliven the memories of how people lived in the past

to

> Buildings enliven the memories of how people lived

to

> Buildings enliven memories

If **buildings enliven memories** is interpreted as a process, it would take the singular **makes**.

If **buildings enliven memories** is interpreted as a series of events, it would take the plural **make**.

So it really amounts to the way you see it.

Comment: Thx for the answer. If what I'm trying to say is a **fact,** so it's neither 'a process' nor 'a series of events' isn't it? Which one should I use then? *makes* or *make*?

Comment: @JohnArvin "(The fact that) **buildings enliven memories** makes each country fascinating...."

Answer (score 1):

If the subject of "makes" is the entire phrase "Historic buildings enliven the memories of how people lived in the past", then it's singular, because we have one (singular) fact that is making someone. For this to be plural, the subject would have to be "historic buildings", but then it should be "Historic buildings enliven the memories of how people lived in the past and make ...".